# First element of aggregation in clickhouse

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, clickhouse

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE address(
   city String,
   street String,
   house String,
   model UInt8
) ENGINE=Memory;
```

For instance, with these data:

```
Paris, aaa, 12a, 10
Paris, bbb, 13a, 20
Berlin, ccc, 14b, 30
Minsk, ddd, 15b, 40
```

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT any(street), any(house)
FROM address WHERE city IN ('Paris', 'Berlin', 'Minsk') 
GROUP BY city, street 
ORDER BY model;
```

But this query non-deterministic - *any* can return first or second row... I need a deterministic query, that returns first row from aggregation. How can I do it with ClickHouse?

Comment: What do you mean by the "first" row? The first row inserted?

Comment: Isn't it a typo - using the column from `group by` in `any` (`street`)? Shouldn't `street` be removed from `group by`? "First row" - in what order exactly? What's the exact expected result on this data?

Comment: I want to get (aaa, 12a), (ccc,14b) and (ddd, 15b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [argMin](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/argmin) function can be used for this with a tuple for 2-nd parameter.
You may use whatever ordering expression needed instead (like just a single column without round brackets).

```
SELECT 
  T.city as city
, argMin (T.street, (T.street, T.house, T.model)) as street
, argMin (T.house,  (T.street, T.house, T.model)) as house
, argMin (T.model,  (T.street, T.house, T.model)) as model
FROM VALUES 
(
'
   city String,
   street String,
   house String,
   model UInt8
'
, ('Paris',  'aaa', '12a', 10)
, ('Paris',  'bbb', '13a', 20)
, ('Berlin', 'ccc', '14b', 30)
, ('Minsk',  'ddd', '15b', 40)
) T
WHERE T.city IN ('Paris', 'Berlin', 'Minsk')
GROUP BY T.city
ORDER BY model
```

| city | street | house | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paris | aaa | 12a | 10 |
| Berlin | ccc | 14b | 30 |
| Minsk | ddd | 15b | 40 |

This works because tuples in ClickHouse are comparable (from left to right) which is suitable for ordering and use here.

```
SELECT ('Paris',  'aaa', '12a', 10) < ('Paris',  'b', '12a', 0)
```

| less(('Paris', 'aaa', '12a', 10), ('Paris', 'b', '12a', 0)) |
| --- |
| 1 |

**Update:**
As for performance. One may compare 2 different approaches of getting the same on their own data.

```
-- 7.3 sec
SELECT 
  T.city                                            as city
, argMin (T.street, (T.street, T.house, T.model))   as street
, argMin (T.house,  (T.street, T.house, T.model))   as house
, argMin (T.model,  (T.street, T.house, T.model))   as model
FROM
(
  SELECT
    'City '   || toString (n.number % 10)   as city
  , 'Street ' || toString (n.number % 1000) as street
  , toString (n.number % 100)               as house
  , n.number % 100                          as model
  FROM numbers (1e7) n
) T
GROUP BY T.city
```

vs

```
-- 13.6 sec
SELECT * EXCEPT rn_
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    T.*
  , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY T.city ORDER BY T.street, T.house, T.model)
        as rn_
  FROM
  (
  SELECT
    'City '   || toString (n.number % 10)   as city
  , 'Street ' || toString (n.number % 1000) as street
  , toString (n.number % 100)               as house
  , n.number % 100                          as model
  FROM numbers (1e7) n
  ) T
)
WHERE rn_ = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Why do I need ORDER BY with avgMin? Model is present in avgMin

Comment: `ORDER BY` is just to order output like in your example. Expression for the 2-nd parameter of `argMin` is for different purpose: to select a sigle row in a group according to the specified order. Whether you need it or not depends on your requirements.

Comment: What about performance? Will be argMin only one call or three calls with ordering?

Comment: @QuickDzen I've updated the answer. You may try to compare both approaches on your own data.

Comment: Now I have problem: DB::Exception: Aggregate function argMin(street, street) is found inside another aggregate function in query: While processing argMin(street, street) AS street. (ILLEGAL_AGGREGATION)

Comment: Always use table aliases if you reuse column names. Like `argMin(T.street, T.street) AS street`. If it doesn't help, then create a new question with a full statement text and error.